# Dynamics CRM 2011 - fetch xml sum returns NULL instead of 0

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I have a fetchXMl which does a simple 'sum' query.

```
<fetch distinct='true' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
  <entity name='orb_timesheetentry'> 
    <attribute name='orb_cost' alias='cost_sum' aggregate='sum'/> 
    <filter type='and'>
      <condition attribute='orb_prepaidpack' operator='eq'  value='{0}' />
      <condition attribute='statuscode' operator='eq' value='169810003' />
    </filter>
  </entity> 
</fetch>
```

The problem is that if it doesn't find any records, it returns *null* instead of 0.

Is there a way to return 0 instead of *null*?

Answer (score 0):

If it's executed from C#:

```csharp
return results ?? 0;
```

If it's executed from JavaScript:

```javascript
if(!results)
  return 0;
return results;
```